# list of registered device drivers in android

Tags: android, list, keyboard, terminal, driver

i have a android system on my mini6410 board.
**can i see the list of registered device drivers?**

note:
android has a terminal emulator in dev tools but this emulator does not have a virtual keyboard.
device dont recognize external usb keyboard. but i can connect to my mini6410 board using usb cable.
using a terminal we can get list of registered drivers using : **ls /dev**
but unfortunately i cant do this without a keyboard :(

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:
to see the content of /dev folder i used the **ES File Explorer** found on main android menu.
just run it and click on sd card icon on the top left corner. (if you cant see the sd card icon click on small window icon on upper right corner).
after click on sd card icon it changes to a home icon. now we are on home of device.
point the folder named dev and here we can find all the registered drivers.
some are in folders and some others are directly in that path(/dev)